# EXE Files downloaded with DownThemAll! in Firefox are not valid Win32 applications

Tags: windows, firefox, download-manager

I'm running Firefox 12.0 with [DownThemAll! 2.0.13](http://www.downthemall.net/) on Vista Business x64. Recently everything that DTA downloads is corrupted. Error message when trying to execute:

```
[Window Title]
C:\Users\me\Downloads\file.exe

[Content]
C:\Users\me\Downloads\file.exe is not a valid Win32 application.


[OK]
```

When I download with Firefox's built-in manager they work fine. I tried resetting DTA's settings to default but that didn't help. Has anyone else run into this?

**Update:** [submitted bug to DownThemAll](https://bugs.downthemall.net/ticket/2203).

Comment: It does indeed seem that others have run into this https://bugs.downthemall.net/report/1 as reported by the number of bugs involving incomplete downloads, corrupt downloads, the occasional inability to get the correct file size, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling logging in the DTA extension, and going through the logs, there were error messages generated by [YSlow](http://yslow.org/). After disabling YSlow and restarting Firefox everything works beautifully again.

Answer (score 0):

That means it's a corrupt download. Download managers are prone to many data corruption issues in cases with inconsistent data connectivity, and it takes a lot of work to make it work the way it's supposed to.

If DownThemAll has a "rollback" option, you should enable it. That means that when a thread is paused or loses connectivity or stalls for whatever reason, instead of continuing where it left off it should rollback a small amount (usually ~4KiB) and start from there. None of this, of course, is actually required if the code properly handles all scenarios and doesn't have any off-by-one bugs, for instance.

Comment: I tried setting it to 4KB but there was no change, thanks though.